# How to prevent network autodetection in debian-install?

Tags: debian, network-interface, debian-installer, sparc

I'm trying to use the Debian install media rescue mode on a Sun Ultra 10 so that I can use the shell to investigate an old SCSI disk I have.

It seems that the last version of Debian where a SPARC build was available with anything more than a netboot image was wheezy (7.x).  I'm using a copy of the 7.11.0 DVD 1 ISO.

When I boot from the disc and proceed through the rescue install prompts I get as far as `Detecting Network Hardware` and at 0% the system hangs.

How can I disable network auto-probing?

[According to the manual for wheezy on SPARC](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/sparc/ch05s03.html.en), the `netcfg/disable_autoconfig` boot parameter is provided for this purpose. However booting with

```
rescue netcfg/disable_autoconfig=true
```

at the SILO prompt does not appear to affect anything -- the `Detecting Network Hardware` step is still eventually shown and the system hangs.

A responder indicated that the boot parameter `netcfg/disable_dhcp=true` is documented in the F8 help on some install media (although not wheezy for SPARC -- it has no such help feature), however I also tried this boot parameter and had a similar result.

In search of ideas, I took a look at [the example preseed file for wheezy](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/example-preseed.txt), and it notes that the `boolean` parameter `netcfg/enable` can be used to entirely disable network configuration; however booting `rescue netcfg/enable=false` also had no effect. Perhaps the parameters just aren't propagating from the SILO prompt to `debian-installer`. Is there an alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `expert` mode installation as a substitute for certain parameters that skip steps -- it goes to the menu before each step which serves as a confirmation, so you can skip network configuration by just never going to that step. If a non-target shell is sufficient for your rescuing needs you can launch it when any other desired steps are done just by choosing it from the menu.